# GWT - Where should i use code splitting while using places/activities/mappers?

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, gwt-mvp

"core" refers to the initial piece of the application that is loaded.

- In order to bind url to places, GWT uses `PlaceTokenizer<P extends Place>`. When loading the application from the url, it calls the method `P getPlace(String token)` to retrieve a new instance of the place to call.

  due to the asynchronous nature of code splitting, I can't create the place inside a `runAsync` in this method. So I have to put **all** the places of my app in the core.
- To link places to activity, GWT calls`Activity getActivity(Place place)` (from `com.google.gwt.activity.shared.ActivityMapper`) to retrieve a new instance of the activity.

  Once again, i have to put **all** my activities in the core.

Here's what I want to try: Write a custom `com.google.gwt.place.shared.Delegate` that

- bind itself on `PlaceChangeRequestEvent`. If the AppPiece corresponding to the requestedPlace isn't loaded, it calls `event.setWarning(NEED_TO_LOAD_MODULE)`
- in the `confirm(String message)` method, **always** return false when the message equals `NEED_TO_LOAD_MODULE` (so it doesn't bother the user), and load the module via `RunAsync`.
- Once the module is loaded, call `goTo(requestedPlace)`

Each AppPiece of my application contains a bunch of activies and the corresponding views. Since the mappers are only called when `PlaceChangeEvent`is fired, i could generate a new instance of my activity via `AppPiece.getSomeActivityInstance()`.

I'm pretty sure this will work, but what bother me is that

- Finding wich AppPiece to load depending on the requestedPlace will force me to write code that will be very similar to my mappers
- I would like to have my places inside the corresponding AppPiece
- Overriding `Delegate` for this purpose is tricky, and I'm looking for a better solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to put all your activities in *the core* (as you call it): while an Activity instance is retrieved synchronously, it's allowed to **start** asynchronously. This is where you'd put your `GWT.runAsync` call.

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5129 and https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/8_P_d4aT-0E/discussion